# I don't know the cause and solution of keyerror

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner.
What I used was flask and pymongo.
If you press the button, it's "Like". It should be +1, but there is a key error at the bottom.

My python route code:

```
@app.route('/api/like', methods=['POST'])
def like_movie():
    title_receive = request.form['title_give']
    movie = db.toytoy.find_one({'title': title_receive})
    current_like = movie['like']
    new_like = current_like + 1
    db.toytoy.update_one({'title': title_receive}, {'$set': {'like': new_like}})
    return jsonify({'msg': 'like!'})
```

This is how I POST from JS

```js
  
 
 function like_movie(title) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/api/like',
                data: {title_give: title},
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    alert(response['msg']);
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
```

I get an exception as below:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
    KeyError: 'title_give'
```

***What I want is if it's 'like_btn'. If you press the button, it becomes +1.***

Answer (score 0):

The base problem in what you did is not respecting `Content-type`. From front JS, you are making a POST with JSON object. Which makes the request to have a content type of `application/json`.

In backend code, you use  `request.form` which expects the request to be in the form encoded types (like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data`) etc.

So, you need to read the JSON content in backend, instead of reading from a form which is not available. Like below:

```
ui_req = request.get_json()
title_receive = ui_req['title_give']
```

And then parse other structures accordingly.